# Spreadsheet Editor's Ability to Run Scripts from Library

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I will be maintaining Google spreadsheets for 100 different schools.  Each school's spreadsheet will have similar functions (e.g., jumping to a certain cell based on the date or creating a note in a certain cell based on inputted text) and multiple people will have access to edit it (e.g., principal, teachers, coaches, etc).  I imagine that creating a library is easiest for this purpose since the functions are the same for each spreadsheet!  For example, the script file for each document uses the `onOpen()` event to call `.addMenu()`.  Then `.addMenu` calls a wrapper function and this function calls the "jumpToToday" method in my library.  (I saw the posts about how the library method cannot be called directly from the menu, so that is why I did it this way).  I have two questions:

1. When I (the owner) share the spreadsheet with an editor, the menu shows up, but when the editor selects one of the menu options, the script returns the error:

   > You do not have access to library `ExternalSupport`, used by your script, or it has been deleted.

   After I saw this, I shared the library file (Can View) with the spreadsheet editor and then it worked.  **Do I have to share the library (view only) with ALL editors of the spreadsheet so that they can run the functions?**  If so, that's fine (I was just trying to avoid it because most principals/teachers/coaches are not techie, so I didn't want to confuse them by sharing a file of code...I just want them to use the spreadsheet).
2. Because the editors of the spreadsheet will only be able to view the library, it seems like they only have access to the Version that is selected (even if dev mode is on).

When I update my library to another version, do I have to go into the Script Editor of all 100 spreadsheets and then go to Resources > Manage Libraries and update the version?  Or is there a way to make all files use the latest version of the library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) **Yes**. According to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guide_libraries#sharinglibrary)

> you must grant at least a read-level access to your project for all potential users.

I agree that this may be confusing for other users but at the moment it is necessary.

2) There is **no** way to make a file use the latest version of a library. Though, there is a way to make a file use the development version of a library. For this to work you need to grant editor-level access to your library to the user. However, bear in mind that any changes that you make to the library will be reflected immediately at the user's end. You can find more information in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guide_libraries#testAndDebug).