# GAS Menu Click function in Library

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

This is a follow-on to question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51012146/google-sheets-menu-click-function-in-library).

Review in linked post: menu click function in a library ('rm' in this case) works.

```
ui.createMenu('Test').addItem('Test-Lib', 'rm.test');
```

**However**, going forward I had found that this **ONLY** works iff the user has **EDIT** access to the (rm) library. I have tested this for "links" "readonly" and "readonly public access". Only works for **EDIT** access.

The background information is that I've found NO information regarding this from Google/Official sources.

Initial finding was good (click function in library) in that it saved me a lot of coding. But now I'm back to square one, as I **cannot** give **edit** access to the library.

Anyone have any experience on this? Ideas? Workarounds? Thoughts?

EDIT;

Big thanks to @tehhowch comment below with his [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19841664/google-apps-script-spreadsheet-editors-ability-to-run-scripts-from-library). Solved it, but still a little bit tedious solution. To summarize:

1. Read-Only access means that user does **not** have access to the development version, but **only** the linked version - so need to **make sure** that linked version has all the requirements met.
2. Republishing the lib to the same version did **not** work.
3. Republishing the lib to a new version and updating the client spreadsheet to the new version **did work**.

Of course, this is a bit tedious going into all client spreadsheets that use the lib, but at least now i can deploy with read-only access to my libs :)

Comment: Well, what error message do you get? Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12842441/spreadsheet-onopen-menu-from-a-library https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19841664/google-apps-script-spreadsheet-editors-ability-to-run-scripts-from-library  Please update your question with any relevant error messages and how you have attempted to resolve your issue.

Comment: @tehhowch Amazing, with your link I was able to solve the issue. Two things.
(1) Read-Only access means that user does NOT have access to the development version, but ONLY the linked version - so need to MAKE SURE that linked version has all the requirements met.
(2) Republishing the lib to the same version did NOT work.
(3) Republishing the lib to a new version and updating the client spreadsheet to the new version DID WORK. Of course, this is a bit tedious, but at least now i can deploy with read-only access to my libs :)